# Make Android Library module without including existing project?

Tags: android, jcenter

I'm currently working on creating my first Android library that I will upload to the jCenter!

But can I delete the app/application folder? Because the only thing I need is the folder `viewtobitmap` which is the library and I'm not planning on making any samples either. Because I dont want to upload a empty app folder to the jCenter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1)Right CLick on project 
2) New 
3)module
4) select which module you want

Comment: just you can add jar lib

Comment: I don't think you understand my problem